# Using IF in MySQL's SELECT subquery

Tags: mysql

I have the following query:

```
  SELECT `users`.`id`, `login`, `fullname`, `active`, `sex`, `height`,
  `special-title`, `language`, `body-fat`,
  `main-photo-id`, `main-photo-offset`, `weight`,
  `objective`, `level`, `config-comments-type`,
  (
     SELECT `type`
     FROM `users-pro`
     WHERE
        (`user` = `users`.`id`)
        AND
        (`starts` <= $time)
        AND(
           (`ends` > $time)
           OR
           (`ends` IS NULL)
        )
     LIMIT 1
  ) as `account_type`
  FROM `users`
```

I'm wondering how/where do I add an `IF` statement, so that if the inner SELECT returns NULL (no entries for the user in `users-pro`, a value `1` would be returned.

This is what I usually do if there is no subquery:

```
SELECT IF(`rank` = 1, `rank`, 0) as `rank`
```

However, I don't know how to do this with a subquery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the ANSI standard `coalesce()` function for this, by wrapping the subquery in it:

```
SELECT `users`.`id`, `login`, `fullname`, `active`, `sex`, `height`,
  `special-title`, `language`, `body-fat`,
  `main-photo-id`, `main-photo-offset`, `weight`,
  `objective`, `level`, `config-comments-type`,
  coalesce((
     SELECT `type`
     FROM `users-pro`
     WHERE
        (`user` = `users`.`id`)
        AND
        (`starts` <= $time)
        AND(
           (`ends` > $time)
           OR
           (`ends` IS NULL)
        )
     LIMIT 1
  ), 1) as `account_type`
  FROM `users`
```

Comment: That seems like a solution, yeah. I'm wondering whether there are no more options for this, but I think I should accept it.

Comment: Although COALESCE will work fine, I believe the most appropriate function from a logical standpoint is [IFNULL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) since it returns another value in case an expression is NULL. Just to clarify: COALESCE accepts multiple arguments and returns the first non-NULL value.

Comment: @setsuna . . . I have a strong preference for using ANSI standard constructs instead of database-specific ones, which is why I generally prefer `coalesce()`.